# How to hook function in Joomla

Tags: api, joomla, joomla2.5

I need to run my component(code) exactly after authorization (before page loading). Is there some features for it without changing source? Maybe some functions, like [add_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) in wordpress or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to create a plugin for this.

> "Plugins provide functions which are associated with trigger events." ([Joomla Wiki Plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin))

To listen to user events you must create a *"User Plugin"*. To hook a function for user authorization see [onUserLogin](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onLoginUser).

See the [wiki page](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin) for more information about plugin developement.

**Edit:**
Since Joomla 1.5 an example of [onUserLogin](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onLoginUser) can be found in a plain Joomla CMS installation at *plugins/user/joomla/joomla.php*.

Comment: is there some examples how to use onLoginUser in 2.5.6 ?